# Converting byte array to PDF and display in JSP page

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am doing a JSP site, where I need to display PDF files.
I have byte array of PDF file by webservice  and I need to display that byte array as PDF file in HTML. My question is how to covert that byte array as PDF and display that PDF in new tab.

Answer (score 3):

save these bytes on the disk by using output stream.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(latest.pdf));

//create an object of BufferedOutputStream
bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

byte[] pdfContent = //your bytes[]

bos.write(pdfContent);
```

Then send its link to client side to be opened from there.
like http://myexamply.com/files/latest.pdf

Answer (score 3):

better is to use a servlet for this, since you do not want to present some html, but you want to stream an byte[]:

```
public class PdfStreamingServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
        IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    public void processRequest(final HttpServletRequest request,
        final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
        IOException {

        // fetch pdf
        byte[] pdf = new byte[] {}; // Load PDF byte[] into here
        if (pdf != null) {
            String contentType = "application/pdf";
            byte[] ba1 = new byte[1024];
            String fileName = "pdffile.pdf";
            // set pdf content
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            // if you want to download instead of opening inline
            // response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
            // write the content to the output stream
            BufferedOutputStream fos1 = new BufferedOutputStream(
                response.getOutputStream());
            fos1.write(ba1);
            fos1.flush();
            fos1.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the use of  URL url1 = new URL(url);                                                              and why are setting like this - byte[] ba1 = new byte[1024];

Comment: you do not need the URL, this was some code i used for something else and i forgot to remove it. as for the byte[], this is the Buffer of BufferedOutputStream.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, you do not tell us what technology you use.

With Spring MVC, use `@ResponseBody` as an annotation for your controller method and simply return the bytes like so:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/pdf/shopping-list.pdf", produces = "application/pdf", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public byte[] downloadShoppingListPdf() {
    return new byte[0];
}
```

Opening in a new tab is an unrelated matter that has to be handled in the HTML.

Comment: iam  using hibernate and jsp  ,how can i perform that action in jsp